# npm install hangs with last statement as extract:npm: sill extract npm@^5.3.0 extracted to /<packageLocation>

Tags: node.js, git, npm-install

I am setting up my git project again and it is getting stuck at npm install step as shown below:

npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.10: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
░░░░░░⸩ ⠴ extract:npm: sill extract npm@^5.3.0 extracted to /

PFB my npm setup:

Node version: 10.16.0
npm version: 6.9.0

I have already tried below solutions but none worked:

1. Changing npm config from https to http
2. Disabling firewall
3. Updating and Reinstalling npm and node
4. setting postBuffer for git config

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the same problem by administration privileges for terminal where npm runs.